# extends class declare properties using interface/type

Tags: typescript

I want declare some properties in class

```
class a extends legacyJsClass {
  declare id: number;
  declare name: string;
}
```

but also want that this properties can be reused in other places, but it isn't work

```
type I = {
  id: number;
  name: string;  
}

class a implements I {} // not work as declare
class a {
  declare [K in keyof I]: I[K]  // syntax don't exist
}
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: What if you use `declare` keyword on the type itself? Another solution could be implementing an interface and adding props manually with `declare` keyword.

Comment: I'm not sure why do you use `declare` keyword. Please see the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html)

Comment: @captain-yossarian it's for projects that has been created in JS, trying to support TS. According to the docs this feature tells the compiler that specific field exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use declaration merging.

Consider this example:

```js
interface Shape {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

class Shape { }

const foo = new Shape()
foo.id // number
foo.name // string
```

However, it is not super safe, because, as you may have noticed, there are no `id` and `name` properties in the class.

Hence, I think this approach is a bit safer:

```js
interface Shape {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

class Foo implements Shape {
  id = 42;
  name = 'John'
}

const foo = new Foo()
foo.id // number
foo.name // string
```

Answer (score 1):

After inspecting the example of captain-yossarian I write next solution

```
export type RawType = {
   name: string;
}

export interface Custom extends RawType {}

export class Custom extends Legacy<genericParam> {
  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```